# How to find out redis server hostname?

Tags: kubernetes

I was thinking of using kubernetes to setup a Redis service to a pod of containers for Redis masters.  I have Node.js connecting to the Redis service but I would like to know which pod it connected to and that in turn figure out which node it connected to.  Is there a way to do that?  I was looking through redis-cli and there doesn't seem to be anything that will return the hostname.

Answer (score 1):

Each pod managed by Kubernetes is created with a set of environment variables.

If you ssh into your pod and run `env | grep HOSTNAME` in your shell you will get the name of the pod. Or just run `env` and explore what is in there.

I'm afraid you cannot get that kind of information within redis. What you can do is store the information into redis when starting your redis pod.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I could store the hostname in redis but if it's being replicated, wouldn't that information be the same regardless which redis master I end up connecting to through the kubernetes service?  Ultimately, I'm looking for some ways to show that the kubernetes service is indeed load balancing and distributing the load to each of the redis master pods.

Comment: If running in GKE, you can expose your service using `kubectl expose` and connect to the cluster IP that is referred to by hostname. The same with mutiple redis instances - you just use sentinel.